# import csv to sqlite3, but change the type of column before import

Tags: csv, sqlite, sqlite-shell

I am working with one csv, which has many columns. I decided I'll import the data via sqlite3 shell and I found this very useful:

```
.mode CSV
.import my_table.csv my_sqlite_table
```

This saves me a lot of work, on the other hand it gives me no control over column and value characteristic as all the data is `TEXT`

Is there any elegant way within shell to first address what type the column should be or to fix particular blank values with `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in CSV files always are strings.

To change that, import into a temporary table, and then modify the values appropriately:

```
INSERT INTO the_actual_table(a, b, c)
SELECT a, CAST(b AS INTEGER), nullif(c, '') FROM temp_table;
```